# How do I get my ball in my bowl and be able to shoot?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]hi, so I have this game Im making on unity3d. As you can see the claw is going to pull the bowl, to which ever direction the user moves the robot arm. My claw hand is made of animation. Everything works except the shooting the ball.  Im using a spring joint on the bowl so it goes back to its place but when i try to grab the bowl, it grabs a specific part of the bowl and it makes the ball come out when i move the ball up, down , left or right. Even though when i play the game and dont move it , the ball stays in the bowl. Maybe because I pull it to fast so the ball falls through the bowl. i dont know how to fix that. if thats the case. This is my code: `

```
public float speed;
private Animation anim;
[SerializeField] bool isClosed;
Rigidbody rb;
public Transform rightClaw;
public Vector3 offset;
Collider objectholder;


void Start()
{

    Debug.Log(transform.position);

    Console.WriteLine("test");
    anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
void Update()
{
    // Debug.Log(transform.position);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X))
    {
        anim.Play("clawopen");
        isClosed = false;

    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Y))
    {
        anim.Play("clawclose");
        isClosed = true;



    }

}
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider objectholder)

{
  
    Rigidbody colRb = objectholder.attachedRigidbody;
    if (isClosed && objectholder.transform.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        objectholder.transform.position = rightClaw.transform.position + offset;

    }

}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider objectholder)

{
    Rigidbody colRb = objectholder.attachedRigidbody;
    if (isClosed && objectholder.transform.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        colRb.Sleep();
    }
}
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider objectholder)

{
    Rigidbody colRb = objectholder.attachedRigidbody;
    if (isClosed && objectholder.transform.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        colRb.WakeUp();
    }

}
```

}
`
How can I make the ball stay in the bowl until it gets let go so it can get thrown . or can I code the ball and this bowl without a spring joint so it can go back to its original place and the ball can shoot.
please and thank you

Comment: The Rigidbodies `sleep` isn't suitable for your application, as they wake up as soon as they touch a collider. You could make the ball's Rigidbody `kinematic` though. It still collides but isn't affected itself by other colliders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my no-script setup:

I would just make the Ball & Bucket `kinematic` until you release it. No matter if It's controlled by animation or scrip/mouse/touch.

I used 2 Spring joints to keep the bucket on an almost straight line between the 2 gray dots. So it accelerates forwards but doesn't spin around.

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkMfs.jpg

[image]

A few notes on this kind of setup: MeshColliders need to be marked "convex" for physics to work. But a bucket collider will be "filled" by checking "convex" so you have to make it submeshes or use a few cube colliders to imitate the buckets shape.

Both, ball and bucket need to have a Rigidbody.

Comment: ok im going to try this. are the two dots a child of the bucket or just seperate? and when you say you can keep the bucket and ball kinematic until you release it should i do a script on that or my claw should be able to release it and the bucket will act as its being thrown back ?

Comment: the gray dots are separate. You could attach the left one to your claw though. Either make them kinematic and animate them. Or just animate the claw, but attach the left dot to the claw, make that dot kinematic. But not the bucket.

Comment: How did you make you boxes fall fast? because my fall very slow. btw thank you so much your example helped :)

Comment: My gravity settings are normal, but I made the boxes really light (0.01). Drag&Angular Drag are at default settings.

Comment: Hey so by any chance where did you put ur anchors for each spring joint ? because after I shoot the boy it starts float around up.

Comment: as you can see in the screenshot, I moved the anchors of the 2 spring joints a bit forward/backward towards the cubes.

Comment: Yea so i did the same but for some reason it keeps floating down and up :/

Comment: The gravity is probably affecting the bucket too much, you can try to lower the bucket's weight or increasing both Spring tensions.